# Windows Phone when should I use the progress indicator text

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, windows-phone, progress-indicator

I have a windows phone app and I have operations that take a while so I am using the indeterminate progress indicator to signal to the user that an operation is happening. Should I use display text in the progress indicator or should I just display the progress bar by itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would display a small text describing what it is doing that is taking a long time.

Take a look at the Windows Phone Guidelines for Progress bar indicator here: [Progress Indicator Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465469.aspx).

Basically use the "..... .... " for operations that is not blocking and use the spinning circle for operations that block the user.  As you can see by the guidelines, they have a simple description of what the phone is currently trying to do.